# Переход между Activity android

Tags: android

Хотелось бы уточнить в чем может заключаться ошибка, препятствующая запуску одного из активити.

```
mStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mStart);
mStart.setText("Continue");
mStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, tesrclass.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Главная активити стартует, открывается лоадбар, через время скрывается и появляется кнопка, после клика на которую должен осуществляться переход, но просто выкидывает.

Comment: Активити в манифесте прописана?

Comment: Покажите стектрейс

Comment: Да,  она прописана.

Comment: Добавьте в манифест <activity android:name=".tesrclass"/> Если же активность прописана, прикрепите логи, готов взяться за вашу проблему и дополнять этот ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое за быстрые ответы! Но проблему устранил. Это был мой косяк с БД, использующейся в сл. активити!

Comment: вот так и знал)) не за что, удачи

Comment: @studer не стоит отмечать как ответ то, что на самом деле не решает проблему.